# xargs doesn't recognize "-n1" when used with "-I%"

Tags: bash, xargs

When invoking `xargs` with only `-n1`, xargs executes a separate `echo` command for every item:

```
$ echo 1 2 | xargs -n1
1
2
```

But when using `-n1` with the `-I` option, which passes the string to be replaced to `xargs`, it passes all the arguments to a single `echo` command, effectively ignoring`-n1`:

```
$ echo 1 2 | xargs -n1 -I% echo %
1 2
```

My goal is to execute an arbitrary command with different arguments:

```
$ echo 1 2 | xargs -n1 -I% mycommand %
# What I want to achieve
mycommand 1
mycommand 2
```

but I'm quite baffled by the behavior I'm seeing, so:

1. Why `xargs` seemingly ignore `-n1`?
2. What is the correct way to do what I am trying to? Note that I don't want to deal with any files while doing so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `xargs(1)`:

> -I replace-str
>   Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with
>                 names  read  from  standard input.  **Also, unquoted blanks do not
>                 terminate input items; instead  the  separator  is  the  newline
>                 character.**  Implies -x and -L 1.

```
$ echo $'1\n2' | xargs -n1 -I% echo %
1
2
$ echo $'1\n2' | xargs -n1 -I% echo '*' %
* 1
* 2
```